# Read line is ignored

Tags: bash, read

I have problem with a simple read. I read a list of items xml items and then I work with them. In some point I need to ask if Im sure and accept this response in a variable. 
My problem is that if I ask into the "while read linea" the "read -p ..." is ignored and I can't answer the question.

```
xml2 < list | egrep "item" | egrep "url|pubDate|title" |  while read linea; 
do 

    case 1 in
        $(($x<= 1)))
            ...
            ;;
        $(($x<= 2)))
            ...
            ;;
        $(($x<= 3)))
            ....                        
            if [ $DIFERENCIA -lt $num_dias ];        
            then  

                ...                             
                read -p “Are you sure: ” sure                              
                ...

            fi                           

            ...
            ;;                
        *)
            let x=1
            ;;
    esac      

done
```

Thanks

Comment: it is not ignoring, it is reading the answer from the STDIN you provided at the beginning of your while loop. And because of that, you are missing some lines from your input file to be processed as well, if you come to think of it

Comment: Without the read line the script work fine, my unique problem is that I want to do a question  to insert or not the item processed.

Comment: @estonolose you may want to put other condition evaluating the `$sure` value. Posiblemente otra condición donde evalues el valor de `$sure` pueda servir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use this one instead :

```
read -p "Are you sure: " sure  </dev/tty
```

Quotes should be ascii 0x22, not UNICODE U-201c `“` and U-201d `”`.

Comment: It doesn't works. This is the ourput

Comment: �AreY
./recopilar_xml2.sh: línea 224: read: `sure:': no es un identificador válido

Comment: your double quotes are looking a little different. Don't know why but just to test, use `echo 'are you sure' ; read sure </dev/tty` construct, instead of `read -p “Are you sure: ” sure  </dev/tty` line

Answer (score 1):

(for bash) Supply the whole command line as input on some other file descriptor `3`:

```
while read -ru 3 linea; do
    read -p "Are you sure: " sure
    echo "sure=$sure linea=$linea"
done 3< <(xml2 < list | egrep "item" | egrep "url|pubDate|title" )
```

And please use the correct ascii for double quote: `"`, not U-201c `“` and U-201d `”`.